# Filling a DataTable

Tags: asp.net

In my asp page users can search students from TextBox and a search button. Every time they made a search a student object returns. I just want to be able to fill a gridview with student object but every time page loads, the page doesn't remember the former searches. What I mean by this, my gridview turns out empty. How can I fill a gridview?

```
List<Student> oList;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        oList = new List<Student>();
    }
}

protected void AddLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Student oStudent = new Search().WithId(StudentIdTextBox.Text);
    // Student object is recevied
    oList.Add(oStudent);
    StudentGridView.DataSource = oList;
    StudentGridView.DataBind();

}

class Student { // Just a simple student class
    int id;
    string name;
    string sname;
}
```

Every time search method is called, I want to be able to put the student data to DataTable so that I can bind it to GridView. I just dont know how to achieve this.

Comment: could you post some code please?

Comment: please also post the gridview code and the datatable from the aspx page.

Comment: @w0051977, more details added.

Comment: @w0051977, list gets created everytime page does postback so former information gets lost.

Comment: have you tried to use Page.IsPostBack? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Comment: @AnarchistGeek, oList = new List<Student>(); this line in `if (IsPostBack)
        {oList = new List<Student>();}` and still doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: @Mehmet Budak, I am not clear what you are tryin to do here: new Search().WithId(StudentIdTextBox.Text).  Is there some code missing?

Comment: I have some questions, why would you need to create List on page load? I assume you load data from database, there do you do that? it is gridview data filtering to me, you need to filter your datasource, and re-bind your gridview.

Comment: @AnarchistGeek, but I should be able to store Student ids somehow without storing them in db so that I can use it somewhere else.

Comment: @w0051977, just a simple search method, all you have to know is after id is entered to the textbox, method returns a student object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want to achieve something like this? I will improve my answer if you need.

it stores the list in a session object and bind the grid from session object.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<Student> oList = new List<Student>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["List"] = oList;
        }

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = Session["List"] as List<Student>;
        list.Add(new Student() { id = 1, name = "new", sname = "added" });
        Session["List"] = list;
        GridView1.DataSource = list;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
public class Student
{ // Just a simple student class
    public int id{get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}
    public string sname{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I stated before, student object is returned after this  `Student oStudent = new Search().WithId(StudentIdTextBox.Text); `. I don't load student information manually. and when Add button is clicked I call a student object, add it to oList.

Comment: ok, you might need to store your List in a Session object and use it. let me edit my code